# Why does integration have to be the reverse operation of differentiation?

Tags: calculus, integration, differential

I am in High school and when I was learning calculus, we were taught that integration is nothing but the reverse of differentiation.

But I really don't get it why does that needs to be the case.

Differentiation relates slope of a function and the rate at which the output is changing for given input whereas with integration we are talking about area under a curve. I don't understand how both of these are related and reverse operations of each other.

Can someone explain me why do these have to be the reverse operations of each other.

Comment: Please can someone teach me how to search for questions

Comment: One thing that can cause confusion is that sometimes the terms "antiderivative" and "integral" are used interchangeably. I prefer not to blur those two concepts. The fundamental theorem of calculus tells us that $\int_a^x f(t) dt$ is an antiderivative of $f$ (assuming $f$ is continuous), but it's not immediately obvious that this should be true.

Comment: Think about the rate that the area changes.

Comment: @RandomAspirant: Google is usually better than math.SE's own search box. Like this: https://www.google.com/search?q=site:math.stackexchange.com+integration+reverse+operation